How can i smooth out this sphere but maintaining the hole i cut?
i want to create a smooth sphere but with a hole in it. Every time i apply the subsurface modifier the hole lookes really messy. I already tried different ways, but cant get my head around it. If anybody can tell me what im missing, thanks a lot in advance.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/how-to-cut-a-rounded-hole-in-a-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248388/cutting-a-circular-hole-into-a-sphere-without-artifacts

Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-
